# Center each label around a switch that has two or more lines

Tags: javascript, html, switch-statement, materialize, text-align

I am working with a switch, and because the actual label is wide, I want to break each labeled part. The issue is that I cannot find a way to break it such that it aligns with the switch widget.

I have tried to make a new line with both `<br>` and `<br/>`. I have also tried to put the text in `<p> ... </p>` but it did not work either. The code I used is the following:

```
<div class="switch">
  <label>
    Off <br/> 0
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="lever"></span>
    On <br/> 1
  </label>
</div>
```

I want to obtain something like in the right green box rather than the one in the red box, see the picture below:

[image]

In other words, each label should be centered around the switch.

The code and the result can also be seen on [codepen](https://codepen.io/tsai_94/pen/BEMbqg).

Comment: use some type of grid layout

Comment: Nicely formatted first question +1. Yeah, like appls said, I would just take the text out of the label, and put the whole thing in a horizontal flex-box grid

Comment: Does "grid layout"/"horizontal flex-box grid" imply actions similar to the CSS part that  nhannt210695 posted below? @Alicia when you say " take the text out of the label" do you imply to introduce some nodes instead of each "text-label-part"? If that is the case, could you suggest some handy keywords that I can look into?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML

```
<div class="switch">
    <label>
      <div class="nhannt210695">
             Off <br/> 0
              <input type="checkbox">
              <span class="lever"></span>
              On <br/> 1
      </div>
    </label>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.nhannt210695 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input").change(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
      console.log("Is checked");
    }
    else {
      console.log("Is Not checked");
    }
  })
});
```